# Adding color to particular cell in table by its id

Tags: javascript

```
function grid(rows, cols) {
  var table = "<table id = \"myTable\">";
  var size = (1 / rows * 525) + "px";
  for (i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    table += "<tr>";
    for (j=0; j<cols; j++) {
    var ID = i+','+j;
    table += "<td id = \"ID\" >"+"</td>";
    }
    table += "</tr>";
  }
  table += "</table>";


  var ID2 = randomFunction(rows, cols);
  alert(ID2);
  document.ID2.style.color = "red";
  //document.getElementById(ID2).style.color = "#ff0000";
  //table1.rows[1].cells[0].style.backgroundColor = "#003F87";
  //id.style.backgroundColor='#003F87';
   $("#container").empty().append(table);
}
```

I have generated table dynamically in javaScript specifying number of rows and columns. I have given id to each cell. I need to change the color of particular cell whose id is generated by random function. I tried in different ways but no solution.

Comment: when do you want to change the color? Is it onClick? Or is it something else?

Comment: You need to run this line, `$("#container").empty().append(table);` before your try add a color, as of now the table is not yet added to the DOM and therefore not work.

Comment: Check the rendered markup after you run this. I suspect your cells will all have the an id attribute equal to "ID". It looks like you're escape the quotes which means ID is part of the literal string. You want to probably not escape them and concatenate your ID variable in instead.

Comment: I want to change the color as soon as the page is loaded. It is not on click.
This code is part of game I'm designing. I even tried by running  `$("#container").empty().append(table);` before adding color but no change is there

Answer (score 2):

One by one:

```
 document.getElementById(ID2).style.color = "#ff0000";
```

won't work, because at this moment, the table is not in the dom, so `document.getElementById(ID2)` will return nothing.

```
 table1.rows[1].cells[0].style.backgroundColor = "#003F87";
```

won't work, because `table` is a regular string, and strings don't have a `rows` property.

```
 id.style.backgroundColor='#003F87';
```

won't work because `id` is again, a simple string. What would work is, to add the table to the dom first, using `$("#container").empty().append(table);`, and then do the setting of the color, using straightforward

```
 document.getElementById(ID2).style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
```

or with jquery:

```
$("#"+ID2).css({backgroundColor: "#ff0000"}).
```

I would also recommend inserting a space (`&nbsp;`) in the table cells (note that your current code is incorrect, it sets the id for all the cells to the string "ID"), using

```
table += '<td id = "'+ID+'">&nbsp;</td>';
```

otherwise the table could be rendered a little odd. Also id in the format 1,2 might cause problems, how about

```
var ID = 'td_'+i+'_'+j;
```

which gives you an ID like td_1_2, which won't mess up any browser.

Comment: Thank You very much @SWeko, it really helped me